# Table value doesn't change

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a 2 dim array and all it's cells filled with zeros.

What i'm trying to do is to take some randomly chosen cells and fill it with 4 or 5

but what i get is either empty gird with all value equal to zero or i get just one value that has changed to 4 or 5 and that's my code below:

```
     local grid = {}
  for i=1,10 do
    grid[i] = {}
    for j=1,10 do
      grid[i][j] = 0
    end
  end

  local empty={}
  for i=1,10 do
    for j=1,10 do
      if grid[i][j]==0 then
        table.insert(empty,i ..'-'.. j)
      end
    end
  end
  local fp=math.floor(table.maxn(empty)/3)
  local fx,fy
  for i=1,fp do

    math.randomseed(os.time())
    math.random(0,1)
    local fo=math.random(0,1)
    math.random(table.maxn(empty))
    local temp= empty[math.random(table.maxn(empty))]
    local dashindex=string.find(temp,'-')

     fx=tonumber(string.sub(temp,1,dashindex-1))
     fy=tonumber(string.sub(temp,dashindex+1,string.len(temp)))
    if fo==0 then
      grid[fx][fy]=4
    elseif fo==1 then
      grid[fx][fy]=5
    end
end


for i=1,10 do
  for j=1,10 do
    print(grid[i][j])
  end
  print('\n')
end
```

Comment: when i debug my code i get a correct result 
but when i run it i don't and i print out the fx and fy each time and i get that they are the same each time

Comment: `math.randomseed(os.time())` must not be inside a cycle.  Just at the the beginning of your code.

Comment: thanks @EgorSkriptunoff but i also tried to multiply i by os.time and it's work i  was get the same value each time

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lua math.random not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199844/lua-math-random-not-working)

Comment: @Tony As Egor told you, you can't seed the RNG in your loop. "seeding" an RNG is an *initialization* step. If you keep initializing it, it will always return the same value. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed).

Comment: @Mud but i get same result every time i run my code if i initialize my seed just one time time

Comment: See the answer that Yu Hao linked to. You probably need to call random a few times before your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `for i=1,fp` loop is doing with `temp` and `fo`, for example the seed should only be set once, and also, the return value on line after `local fo` is ignored, seems very messy. But based on your post, if you really just want to randomly select N cells from your 2D array and set those to either 4 or 5 (randomly), this should work:

```
-- maybe N = fp
local N = 5
math.randomseed(os.time())
local i = 1
repeat
    fx = math.random(1, 10)
    fy = math.random(1, 10)
    if grid[fx][fy] == 0 then
        grid[fx][fy] = math.random(4,5)
        i = i + 1
    end
until i > N
```

Note however that the closer N is to number of items in array (100 in your example), the longer it will take for the loop to complete. If this is a concern, then for large N values, you could do the opposite: initialize each cell to 4 or 5 randomly, and then randomly set size - N of them to 0.

```
math.randomseed(os.time())

local rows = 10
local columns = 10
local grid = {}

if N > rows*columns/2 then 
    for i=1,rows do
        grid[i] = {}
        for j=1,columns do
            grid[i][j] = math.random(4,5)
        end
    end

    local i = 1
    repeat
        fx = math.random(1, 10)
        fy = math.random(1, 10)
        if grid[fx][fy] ~= 0 then
            grid[fx][fy] = 0
            i = i + 1
        end
    until i > N

else
    for i=1,rows do
        grid[i] = {}
        for j=1,columns do
            grid[i][j] = 0
        end
    end

    local i = 1
    repeat
        fx = math.random(1, 10)
        fy = math.random(1, 10)
        if grid[fx][fy] == 0 then
            grid[fx][fy] = math.random(4,5)
            i = i + 1
        end
    until i > N
end
```

Comment: thanks @Scholli for your answer it's work but i don't know why some times i got same result each time i run that code same random value maybe the IDE cash some value or i don't know why i got like this result and for the second solution no it doesn't work in my case

Comment: @Tony if you want the random numbers to be the same each time you run, you need to set the seed to some constant that you choose (do a web search for how to choose good seeds, but an arbitrary value like 7861231 should be fine).