# Lua (Lapis) random values returns the same result even using randomseed

Tags: lua

At first, I use this:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
```

This function to check:

```
function makeString(l)
        if l < 1 then return nil end
        local s = "" 
        for i = 0, l do
            n = math.random(0, 61)--61
            n0 = 0
            if n < 10 then n0 = n + 48
            elseif n < 36 then n0 = n - 10 + 65
            else n0 = n - 36 + 97 end
                s = s .. string.char(n0) 
        end
        return s
end
```

If I use this function:

```
app:match("/tttt", function()
  local ss = ""
   for i=1,10 do ss = ss .. makeString(30) .. "\n" end
  return ss
end)
```

I receive good different values.

If I use this:

```
app:match("/ttt", function()
  return makeString(30)
end)
```

and JavaScript jQuery,
:

```
  $("#button5").click(function(){
   var ss = ""
   for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        $("#div1").load("/ttt", function() {
        ss = ss + $(this).text()
  alert(ss);
});
    }
    $("#div1").text(ss);
  });
```

I recieve the same random strings every one second.
How to fix it? I tried to create database with different random data but I recieve the same strings!!! This is just example I wrote but filling the database gives the same result!@#%%

Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Does popping a few random numbers before real use help? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199844/lua-math-random-not-working/18199908#18199908).

Comment: No it doesn't help. The same result. As I understood, this bug appears if I try to retrive a random data within 1 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is "feature" of lua to generate random using seconds. Use this link to read more: http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial

But the solution which can help is to user /dev/urandom

The link to describe:
http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-05/msg00498.html

In my case example:

```
local frandom = io.open("/dev/urandom", "rb")
local makeString
makeString = function(l)

        local d = frandom:read(4)
        math.randomseed(d:byte(1) + (d:byte(2) * 256) + (d:byte(3) * 65536) + (d:byte(4) * 4294967296))

        if l < 1 then return nil end
        local s = "" 
        for i = 0, l do
            local n = math.random(0, 61)
            n0 = 0
            if n < 10 then n0 = n + 48
            elseif n < 36 then n0 = n - 10 + 65
            else n0 = n - 36 + 97 end
                s = s .. string.char(n0)
        end
        return s
end
```