# Lua 5.1.4 math.random not actually random

Tags: function, math, random, lua

my problem is when i write `math.random(10)` it is not actually random it always give me output:

`1
6
2
9`

and if i have used for example:

```
local colors = {"ORANG","BLUE","RED","YELLOW","BLACK"}
print(colors[math.random(#colors)])
print(colors[math.random(#colors)])
print(colors[math.random(#colors)])
print(colors[math.random(#colors)])
print(colors[math.random(#colors)])
print(colors[math.random(#colors)])
print(colors[math.random(#colors)])
print(colors[math.random(#colors)])
os.execute 'pause'
```

The output is always:

```
ORANGE
RED
ORANGE
BLACK
RED
RED
BLUE BLACK
```

This is always the output, how could it be random????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lua math.random not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199844/lua-math-random-not-working)

Answer (score 6):

You're misunderstanding what `random` does:

It's a *pseudorandom number generator*. This means that, given a specific *seed*, it will always give you the exact *same* sequence of numbers.

Typically, you use a seed from an external source, e.g. use the current time as seed (WARNING: This is cryptologically dangerous!).

Please read up on pseudorandom and how to use Lua's random library.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer, you need to put:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
math.random(); math.random(); math.random()
```

before using math.random()

Comment: But make sure to call `math.randomseed` only *once* in your program, not  every time you call `math.random`.