# Is there a good way to generate random data in Lua with no repeats?

Tags: random, lua

I asked this question before, but didn't receive the answer I was looking for. Upon inspection, this is my fault, as I didn't make clear what my goal was, and I am sorry. I am making code for an AP Statistics class I'm taking in which random data with no repeats must be generated. The TI Calculator uses Lua, so I was hoping I could make a program that not only generates the numbers, but also answers the question for me, just to shorten the amount of time required. The name of the assignment is "ESP." I'll shorten the scenario for times sake, there are two people, Amy and Ben, they write there name on two index cards, then put their card in an envelope. Now there are two envelopes with two people's names in them. A third person gives these two individuals an envelope. The assignment was to simulate 20 or more trials. A trial being the person giving them the envelopes. Here is the code I wrote to simulate this:
math.randomseed(os.time())

```
Amy = 0
Ben = 1

print("Enter the number of trials you want to simulate.")

res = io.read()

for c = 1, res do
    print("Trial #"..c)

    Amy_ = Amy - math.random(0, 1)
    if Amy_ == 0 then
        print("Amy = match")
    elseif Amy_ ~= 0 then
        print("Amy = not a match")
    end

    Ben_ = Ben - math.random(0, 1)
    if Ben_ == 0 then
        print("Ben = match")
    elseif Ben_ ~= 0 then
        print("Ben = not a match")
    end

end

while true do
end
```

The problem with this is that you could get a result that says:
Trial # 1
Amy = match
Ben = no match

However, it is impossible for only one person to get a match and vis versa. So I was looking to see if there was a way to avoid repeats with 10 people in stead of 2. Also, the program to tell me how many times a certain amount of matches happened per trial. For example the program would say "3 matches - 2 times", which means that out of 'n' trials, 2 trials had 3 matches. A match being they got the envelope with their name. Maybe this will involve the Fisher-Yates Shuffle. Now that I have clearly re-stated my goal, is this possible? Also, the reason why I set Amy = 0 and Ben = 1 is because in the original assignment, there were 10 people, 0 - 9, also, originally I named them a - j, I just chose Amy and Ben so that it's easier to see what the goal is with this Lua program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating uniform random numbers in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154991/generating-uniform-random-numbers-in-lua)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people often face this same problem, here I provide the solution that helps probably about 99% of them:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
```

It sets the seed to the unix time, which is always changing, so it'll be different each time.

But only put it on top of the script though, don't use it multiple times.

If you wish to ignore repeats entirely:

```
local left = {}
for i = 1,10 do
    left[i] = i
end

local function Random()
    return table.remove(left, math.random(#left))
end

for i = 1,10 do
    print(Random())
end
```

You can easily modify this to wrap up Random to take any range of numbers.

Comment: This helps but does not guarantee that there'll be no repeats. In fact, a random stream must contain repeats.

Comment: @lhf Oh I misunderstood his question.

Comment: Fixes: Missing ending parenthesis in Random's return and print(Random()) at the end

Comment: @tony Thanks. Man my coding is getting sloppy recently. I need more practice lol

Comment: It returns 1, 7, 3, 9, 6, 5, 4, 10, 8, 2 EVERYTIME for me. There are no repeats, but the set as a whole repeats over and over again. I want something analogous to TI-84's Random no repeat function, as TI is also written in Lua

Comment: I'll break my real goal down:

Comment: @ZackaryCW this is why you use math.randomseed(os.time()) at the beginning of your code, so each time you run the code you get a different seed.

Comment: Yes, I did that after reading this. However, still has the problem of repeats.

Comment: @Zackary You mean it repeat one of the 10 numbers? That's not possible because they get removed from the array of possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are using the wrong algorithm. Instead of generating 10
   independent random numbers, generate an array with `0` to `9`, and
   shuffle it. Take a look at [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).
2. See [Lua math.random not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199844/lua-math-random-not-working).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try it out and see how to works. However, I do want to generate each number independently, as this is for an AP Stats class and MUST be like that. I was hoping someone would tell me how to make it so that the independently generated number only appears once.

Comment: @ZackaryCW Just assign the the values in the shuffled array to the ten variables.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks for helping me, sorry if I'm annoying. I did math.randomseed(os.clock()) It only changed the number that appears over and over again.

Comment: Also, this is only part of a code, the program overall generates a bunch of numbers really quickly, so I would need something that can do the random function over 100,000 times giving me actual random data.